# CORS multiple headers

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've enabled CORS for my web api project before deploying it to local IIS. However, when I try to call a controller method from Angular, I am getting the following error:

> SEC7128: Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are not allowed for CORS response.

To enable CORS on my web api, I've added this line of code to WebApi.config:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

I've also added this attribute to my controller class:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:53720", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by removing this line from my web.config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like error says that header is not allowed. To allow that header you should add header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers

In which you need to add value:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Beside that you also need to add other header names, which you want to use in your responses.

E.g. If you want to use `MyAwesomeHeader` header:
 `{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, MyAwesomeHeader"}`

Comment: _"Like error says you need to add header"_ The error tells the OP to remove a header.

Comment: They are not allowed because you didn't allow them with header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: I managed to solve it by removing this line from my web.config:
`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`

Answer (score 0):

`"*"` as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't work well for all browsers. To be able to call Web API from any site, one can take `Origin` HTTP request header as a single allowed origin, copying it into `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This can be done by following OWIN middleware:

```
class CORSAnyOriginMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    const string OriginHeader = "Origin";
    const string AllowOriginHeader = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

    public CORSAnyOriginMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);

        if (context.Response?.Headers?.ContainsKey(AllowOriginHeader) ?? false &&
            (context.Request?.Headers?.ContainsKey(OriginHeader) ?? false))
            context.Response.Headers[AllowOriginHeader] =
                context.Request.Headers[OriginHeader];
    }
}
```

Sample usage (inside `Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)`):

```
appBuilder.Use<CORSAnyOriginMiddleware>();
```

Comment: _""*" as Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't work well for all browsers"_ Source?

Comment: I managed to solve it by removing this line from my web.config:
`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`